# How can I access the developer console in python using requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request

I am creating a script that logs onto Discord by using a token.

This is my code:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}


with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://discord.com/login'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

In order to actually login using a token I need to run the following code in the browser's developer console:

```js
function login(token) {
setInterval(() => {
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`
}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {
location.reload();
}, 2500);
}

login ("[enter your token here]")
```

I know that this is possible in selenium but I really need to do it in requests.

Comment: I don't think you can use the dev-console because there's no browser associated with a request. IF you're willing/able to use alternative approaches there should be some in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/ddg#17633072) and at the [docs for complicated POST requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: Oh Thanks! But do you know if it's possible in any other language? It has to use the console  so it can log in using a discord token. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965653/how-do-i-run-command-from-web-browser-console-in-python) thread which works on selenium. But I really need something faster since selenium takes way too long. Do you know of any alternatives to requests. That uses the developer console and isn't as slow as selenium?

Comment: I don't, but if you can use JavaScript that's probably your best bet.